run bash script when headphones are connected
I tried searching everywhere for this but couldn't find anything...
I need to run a bash script when my bluetooth headphones are connected.
I use Fedora 40 KDE (pipewire)
KERNEL[1828.123035] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.2/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [1828.129031] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.2/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[1829.045300] add      /devices/virtual/input/input35 (input)
KERNEL[1829.045449] add      /devices/virtual/input/input35/event24 (input)
UDEV  [1829.047715] add      /devices/virtual/input/input35 (input)
UDEV  [1829.071356] add      /devices/virtual/input/input35/event24 (input)


Watch sudo journalctl  --follow  as you connect your headphones, to see what sort of events your system sees. Then you can start to figure out how you can trigger your script.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/354612/how-to-run-a-script-when-i-connect-a-device ?

I tried either but neither works...

@NGS the udev route that Artem links to is the way the rest of your system knows when bluetooth things are connected, so that does work. Can you add the udev script you've tried to your question, the udevadm monitor output when connecting your headphones, and any journalctl output that occurs which might relate to your rule?

here is what I wrote /etc/udev/rules.d/10-bluez.rules:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", RUN+="bash /home/computer/.config/remove_mic_bt"

and here is udevadm monitor:
KERNEL[2722.338070] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.2/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1 (bluetooth) UDEV  [2722.342135] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.2/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1 (bluetooth) KERNEL[2723.224608] add      /devices/virtual/input/input39 (input) KERNEL[2723.224730] add      /devices/virtual/input/input39/event24 (input) UDEV  [2723.227084] add      /devices/virtual/input/input39 (input) UDEV  [2723.251754] add      /devices/virtual/input/input39/event24 (input)

journalctl shows: bluetoothd[1094]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F8_4E_17_E5_E3_52/sep1/fd6: fd(42) ready

can you please add these to your question's text, not just as comment, @NGS? It's very hard to read, since in comments line breaks are not preserved :) Alos, your rule doesn't have any selector set, that will probably not do what you want.

Added it to the question's text!
